# Drying up Tool For Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using rails 2.3.14 that has a lot of code which makes tracking hard. Is there any tool to DRY up some of my codes and also to view which codes are not really working?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear here what you're after.  What do you mean by "tracking"?

If you want to see code that's not used, my first choice would be rcov (for 1.8) or SimpleCov (for 1.9) to check code coverage.

Comment: I'll check on those. Thanks. For tracing codes(codes that function that needs refactoring/ code revision). I have jumbled up codes and needed optimization for my app's faster performance.

Comment: I don't understand rcov. It throws me an error like this: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these Railscasts:

- [#252 Metrics Metrics Metrics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/252-metrics-metrics-metrics)
- [#358 Brakeman](http://railscasts.com/episodes/358-brakeman)

They cover many automated code analysis tools which might give you some hints on where to start.

But none of these tools is a replacement for **automated tests**. If you don't have any I suggest you create them first.

Comment: I'll check on the link you gave me. Automated tests? How does that work?

Comment: Are these gems compatible with rails 2.3.14?

Comment: Automated tests = unit tests, either using plain `Test::Unit` or `RSpec` for example. Essentially the stuff thats in the `test` directory of your Rails project.